# openmpi: how to send a not connected datablock from one rank to all other ranks?

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

i am looking for a MPI function/method that allows to deliver multiple data blocks from one process to all others. Similar to MPI_Bcast but with multiple blocks at the same time?

I have a fragmented data block on the root rank:

```
#define BLOCKS 5
#define BLOCKSIZE 10000

char *datablock[BLOCKS];
int i;
for (i=0; i<BLOCKS; i++) datablock[i] = (char*)malloc(BLOCKSIZE*sizeof(char))
```

this is just an example but it is clear that the the BLOCKS are not necessary adjacent. I want this datablock delivered to all other ranks (where i allready have prepared the necessary memory to store it).

I noticed that there are methods like MPI_Gatherv or MPI_Scatterv which allow to gather or scatter fragmented data using a displacement array, the problem is that scatter sends each fragment to a different rank, i need to send all fragments to all other ranks, something like a MPI_Bcast with displacment information, like MPI_Bcastv.

One solution would be to have multiple MPI_Bcast calls (one for each block) but i am not sure if this is the best way to do this.

UPDATE: 
I will try the MPI_Ibcast method here is want i think should work:

```
int rank; // rank id
int blocksize = 10000;
int blocknum = 200;
char **datablock = NULL;
char *recvblock = NULL;
MPI_Request *request;
request = (MPI_Request *)malloc(blocknum*sizeof(MPI_Request));
if(rank == 0) {
    // this is just an example in practice those blocks are created one the fly as soon as the last block is filled
    datablock = (char**)malloc(blocknum*sizeof(char*));
    for (i=0; i<BLOCKS; i++) datablock[i] = (char*)malloc(blocksize*sizeof(char));
    for (i=0; i<blocknum; i++)
        MPI_Ibcast(datablock[i], blocksize, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, request[i]);
} else {
    // for this example the other threads know allreay how many blocks the rank 0 has created, in practice this information is broadcasted via MPI before the MPI_Ibcast call
    recvblock = (*char)malloc(blocksize*blocknum*sizeof(char));
    for (i=0; i<blocknum; i++)
        MPI_Ibcast(recvblock+i*(blocksize), blocksize, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, request[i]);
}
MPI_Waitall(blocknum, request, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
```

So, there is a MPI_Waitall missing, i am not sure how to use it, there is a count, an array of requests and an array of statuses needed!?

The reason i have a different MPI_Ibcast for the root and the other ranks is, that the send buffer is not identical with the receive buffer.

Another question is, do i need a different request for each of the MPI_Ibcasts in the for loops, or can i reuse the MPI_request variable as i have done in the example above?

UPDATE2: So i have updated the example, i use a MPI_Request pointer now!
Which i then initialize by the malloc call right after the defintion, this seems pretty odd i guess but this is just an example and in practice the number of requests needed is only known during runtime. I am especially worried if i can use sizeof(MPI_Request) here or if this is problematic because this is not standard data type?

Apart from that, is the example correct? Is it a good solution if i want to use MPI_Ibcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Would serialization be a good idea ? For instance, you can copy the multiple buffers into a single one, broadcast it and then unpack it on the receiver side. [It is the way `boost.mpi` handles complex objects (in c++)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html)
- Alternatively, you can use multiple calls to the non-blocking version of `MPI_Bcast()`: `MPI_Ibcast()`, followed by a single call to `MPI_Waitall()`.
- Notice that the data you are describing looks like a 2D array. There is a way to allocate it in a different way, so that the whole data is contigous in memory:

  ```
  int block=42;
  int blocksize=42;
  char **array=malloc(block*sizeof(char*));
  if(array==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n";exit(1);}
  array[0]=malloc(block*blocksize*sizeof(char));
  if(array[0]==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n";exit(1);}
  int i;
  for(i=1;i<block;i++){
      array[i]=&array[0][i*blocksize];
  }
  ```

Then, a single call to `MPI_Bcast()` is sufficient to broacast the whole array:

```
MPI_Bcast(array[0], block*blocksize, MPI_CHAR,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

EDIT: Here is a solution based on your code, to be compiled by `mpicc main.c -o main -Wall` and ran by `mpirun -np 4 main`:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    int  size, rank;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);    

    int i;
    int blocksize = 10000;
    int blocknum = 200;
    char **datablock = NULL;
    char *recvblock = NULL;
    MPI_Request requests[blocknum];
    MPI_Status status[blocknum];

    if(rank == 0) {
        // this is just an example in practice those blocks are created one the fly as soon as the last block is filled
        datablock = malloc(blocknum*sizeof(char*));
        if(datablock==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n"); exit(1);}
        for (i=0; i<blocknum; i++){
            datablock[i] = (char*)malloc(blocksize*sizeof(char));
            if(datablock[i]==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n"); exit(1);}
            datablock[i][0]=i%64;
        }
        for (i=0; i<blocknum; i++)
            MPI_Ibcast(datablock[i], blocksize, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[i]);


    } else {
        // for this example the other threads know allreay how many blocks the rank 0 has created, in practice this information is broadcasted via MPI before the MPI_Ibcast call
        recvblock = malloc(blocksize*blocknum*sizeof(char));
        if(recvblock==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n"); exit(1);}
        for (i=0; i<blocknum; i++)
            MPI_Ibcast(recvblock+i*(blocksize), blocksize, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[i]);
    }

    int ierr=MPI_Waitall(blocknum, requests, status); 
    if(ierr!=MPI_SUCCESS){fprintf(stderr,"MPI_Waitall() failed rank %d\n",rank);exit(1);}


    if(rank==0){
        for(i=0;i<blocknum;i++){
            free(datablock[i]);
        }
        free(datablock);
    }else{
        for(i=0;i<blocknum;i++){
            if(recvblock[i*(blocksize)]!=i%64){
                printf("communcation problem ! %d %d %d\n",rank,i, recvblock[i*(blocksize)]);
            }
        }
        free(recvblock);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I believe that an optimal implementation would a mix between serialization and `MPI_IBcast()` to limit both the memory footprint and he number of messages.

Comment: I am not sure about serialization, because in practice there are not just 5 blocks but a lot more, and they are pretty big, so copying them all over into one large block, would need some time and also would mean to double the memory need during the copy process. Which i would like to avoid if necessary. I think the MPI_Ibcast approach is the best for my. I will make a example and post it.

Comment: @Oliver : Yes, each `MPI_Ibcast()` must have its own request in an array of requests and `MPI_Waitall()` must be given the number of requests and the array of requests.

Comment: Ok i have updated the initial post, could you please check if this is correct?

Comment: @Oliver : I believe your code is correct, except for the use of the good old `i<BLOCKS;` ! I added a code based on yours to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i needed some time to implement this in my program, some adjustments where also needed, but it works very good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple bcasts (and using `Ibcast` might be a good idea then) but if you want to try sending everything in one go, checkout the `MPI_Type_hindexed` derived datatype.